# JQuery conflict in the angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I got $ with JQuery inside it in my application.

[image]

Instead of this one: (where are jqwidgets used)

[image]

$ with JQuery is from time to time and it's causing crash of my application.
Do you know someone what could be wrong there?
Thanks for some hints :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use jQuery within Angular apps, but that's up to you.

If you want to use it, you need to import it to your bundle system, if it's angular-cli, inside of the scripts attribute and then, install the @types for jQuery. That would bring you typings (intellisense) also.

You might need to import it where you need it, like:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been in wrong order of scripts in the page.
First should be jQuery and then angular scripts.